# Sell a page, page subscription with Wordpress, Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We would like to setup a wordpress website and restrict the access to pages to "subscribed" users. There will be different subscription types/levels or smth similar.

We would like to sell these pages to the users with woocommerce. 
Is this somehow possible out of the box? With plugins or anything?

Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, I have found these plugins that might deliver what I need.

https://www.wpmayor.com/wordpress-plugins-restricting-content-access/